# Class not found fuelphp oil

Tags: php, ubuntu, fuelphp

i am trying to run fuelphp 1.6 oil on ubuntu server and i get this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Error' not found in /home/user/public_html/fuel/core/bootstrap.php on line 79

Fatal error: Class 'Error' not found in /home/user/public_html/fuel/core/bootstrap.php on line 79
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Config' not found in /home/user/public_html/fuel/core/bootstrap.php on line 47

Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in /home/user/public_html/fuel/core/bootstrap.php on line 47
```

The command i run:

```
php oil
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct /home/user/public_html/ isn't the default path for ubuntu server and apache it would normally be /var/www/  or if you've changed it to a users home folder you wouldn't have a user called "user" so it'd be /home/dave/public_html/ or /home/dave/www/ for example

Comment: i changed the path from /var/www to /home/[[user-name any user]]/public_html/..etc

Comment: has the www-data user got access to that folder then ?

Comment: sure i give the access to www-data user

Answer (score 0):

Probably your [autoloader](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/autoloader.html) in not correctly configured. This is the first place I would look.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to configure in Fuel's autoloader.

FuelPHP uses the COREPATH constant defined in your index.php to find the framework's core classes, and this is defined correctly unless you have changed the location of the files.